# Find Models with PaperTrail included on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paper-trail-gem

I'm implementing a form in Rails to search previous versions of a record -
 versioning implemented with PaperTrail gem. The form will contain a dropdown menu for object type (i.e. the model) so I need an array of model names where PaperTrail is included, which might change in the future so I want to avoid hardcoding, to populate the select values. Unfortunately, I've been unsuccessful thus far; I couldn't find anything in the PaperTrail docs and #reflect_on_all_associations isn't working.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A minor improvement to the original response:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.reduce([]) do |arr, model| 
  PaperTrail.request.enabled_for_model?(model) ? arr.push(model.name) : arr
end
```

Note the original solution resulted in repeated deprecated warnings:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: MyModel.paper_trail.enabled? is deprecated, use
> PaperTrail.request.enabled_for_model?(MyModel). This new API makes it
> clear that this is a setting specific to the current request, not all
> threads. Also, all other request-variables now go through the same
> `request` method, so this new API is more consistent. (called from
> block in  at (pry):69)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution shortly after posting. I iterated over the descendants of ActiveRecord::Base (this would be ApplicationRecord for Rails 5 apps), which all models inherit from and used #reduce with a helper function included in PaperTrail (namely: paper_trail.enabled?).

```
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.reduce([]) do |arr, model| 
  model.paper_trail.enabled? ? arr.push(model.name) : arr
end
```

Comment: Make sure all models are loaded before calling `descendants`. In development, you can call `::Rails.application.eager_load!`. In production, eager loading should be on by default.